# How to load data from app start from database using SQFLITE in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sqflite, dart-async

I'm currently developing a side project, but I'll start with a simple problem first. Currently, I can't load how much data (rows) that I have in my SQFLITE database table. It always starts from 0 every time the application starts up, while it should have shown the number of rows that I have in my database table.

Code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  DateTime timestamp = new DateTime.now();
  
  int cout = 0;
  bool _isVisible = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: 
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [Text('Dashboard')],
        )
      ),
      body: StaggeredGridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        crossAxisSpacing: 6.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 6.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
        children: [
          InkWell(
            child: Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Text('Taps', style: TextStyle(height: 2, fontSize: 13), textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '${cout+1}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => new TapHistory()
                )
              );
            },
          ),          
          Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_view_month,),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.donut_large,),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.event_available),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.settings_input_antenna),
            ),
          ),
          Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.explore),
            ),
          ),
          Visibility(
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.message),
                title: Text('News', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              ),
            ),
            visible: _isVisible,
          )          
        ],
        staggeredTiles: [
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 120),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 120),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 120),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 120),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 120),
          StaggeredTile.extent(1, 120),
          StaggeredTile.extent(3, 120),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          int? counter = await TapDatabase.instance.counter();
          setState(() {
            cout = counter!;
          });
          final tap = Taps(
            tapTime: DateTime.now()      
          );
          await TapDatabase.instance.create(tap);
        },
        tooltip: 'Tap to create an object',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Database code:

```
class TapDatabase {
  static final TapDatabase instance = TapDatabase._init();

  static Database? _database;

  TapDatabase._init();

  Future<Database> get database async{
    if (_database != null) return _database!;

    _database = await _initDB('taps.db');
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);

    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);
  }

  Future _createDB(Database db, int version) async{
    final idType = 'INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT';
    final textType = 'TEXT NOT NULL';

    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE $tableTaps (
        ${TapFields.id} $idType,
        ${TapFields.tapTime} $textType
      )''');
  }

  Future <Taps> create(Taps taps) async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final id = await db.insert(tableTaps, taps.toJson());

    // final cols = '${TapFields.id}, ${TapFields.tapTime}';
    return taps.copy(id: id);
  }

  Future <Taps> readTaps(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    final maps = await db.query(
      tableTaps,
      columns: TapFields.values,
      where: '${TapFields.id} = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );

    if(maps.isNotEmpty){
      return Taps.fromJson(maps.first);
    }else{
      throw Exception('ID $id not found');
    }
  }

  Future <List<Taps>> readAllTaps() async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final descOrder = '${TapFields.tapTime} DESC';
    final result = await db.query(tableTaps, orderBy: descOrder);

    return result.map((json) => Taps.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Future<int?> countTaps() async {
    final db = await instance.database;
    final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableTaps');
    int? count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(result);
    return count;
  }

  Future<int?> counter() async {
    TapDatabase TapHelper = TapDatabase.instance;
    int? counter = await TapHelper.countTaps();
    return counter;
  }

  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    final db = await instance.database;

    return await db.delete(
      tableTaps,
      where: '${TapFields.id} = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }

  Future close() async{
    final db = await instance.database;

    db.close();
  }
}
```

After hot restart:

[image: And here's the screenshot after Hot Restart]

What I want from the start of the application:

[image: Here's what I want from the start of the application]

Comment: Can you please provide how you load/store your data in the database?

Comment: @quoci I just edited the question to add my code for CRUD

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, I solved the problem already using `FutureBuilder`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).